# How to understand "Please be sure to keep me posted as to your graduation date."

Tags: meaning

The hr manager emailed me with this sentence "Please be sure to keep me posted as to your graduation date."

what exactly the manage mean? Thanks.

Comment: It means he wants to know when you're going to graduate, and you should tell him if the expected date changes.

Comment: [Keep posted](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+posted)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, "Let me know the date [of your graduation] and update me if it changes".